# api deploynment stages not showing up when creating Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

[Screen shot of how the lambda function looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCYoT.png)

I am trying to set up a lambda function. I created an API gateway called LambdaTest. I tried creating a lambda function and connect it to the API gateway, but there is no drop down list by deployment stage. As you can see in the picture, the drop down list is empty. And it doesn't let me create the Lambda function without putting in a deployment stage, so what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to configure and deploy an API endpoint.

In the 'Resources' section of your API in the API Gateway console, you need to create a method (e.g., PUT), by clicking 'Actions', and then 'Create Method'. After you've created a method, you need to deploy your API by clicking 'Actions', and then 'Deploy API'. You will then be prompted to pick (or create a new) stage. You can then choose this stage in the Lambda trigger creation menu.